# Adding commas to numbers in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm using the following code -

```
converted = num_string.reverse.scan(/{3}|.+/).join(",")
```

where `num_string` is a `.to_s` converted integer. I get the error -

```
target of repeat operator is not specified: /{3}|.+/
```

It's probably obvious, but I just can't see it.

Comment: input string and output string please... `/{3}|.+/` is not correct regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
def add_commas(num_string)
  num_string.reverse.scan(/\d{3}|.+/).join(",").reverse
end

irb(main):018:0> add_commas("1234567")
=> "1,234,567"
```

Comment: Though actually, `/.{3}|.+/` <adding a dot to beginning of regex> also seems to work. Any idea what's the difference between these?

Comment: @RADan: the error message you are seeing says it clearly: `{3}` means "repeat 3 times". But what? `.{3}` means "repeat `.` (i.e. any character) 3 times".

Comment: @RADan try to run both versions on string containing some other characters than just digits, you'll see the difference then.

Comment: @RADan `.` means any character while `\d` means digit characters

Comment: **doesn't work** buddy! `-456565.to_s.reverse.scan(/\d{3}|.+/).join(",").reverse` => `-,456,565`

Comment: @PaulD The regex `/\d{3}-?|.+/` works correctly for your example